# fsl_dpa NIC memory leak?

Tags: memory-leaks, nic

I encountered a memory leak issue which led to system crash。
Analyzing vmcore, found that there are so many skb(list as below) not freed.

```
crash> kmem -s |grep  skbuff_head_cache
ffff80007b2a0c00      256     426183    426416  26651     4k  skbuff_head_cache
```

most of them are multicast or broadcast packets.
most of them are on eth4.

```
crash> sk_buff.dev -x ffff8000095a5500
        dev = 0xffff800063129000
crash> net
   NET_DEVICE     NAME   IP ADDRESS(ES)
ffff80007b2ca000  lo     127.0.0.1
ffff800063124000  eth0   
ffff80007b2c0000  eth1   192.168.1.4
ffff800063126000  eth2   
ffff80006362d000  eth3   169.254.200.1
ffff800063129000  eth4
```

NIC information

```
[root@localhost ~]# ethtool -i eth4
driver: fsl_dpa
version: 
firmware-version: 0
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: soc:fsl,dpaa
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

second time, I found that the leaked packets could be freed by DOWN/UP the NIC eth4.

```
[root@localhost log]# cat /proc/slabinfo |grep skbuff_head;date
skbuff_head_cache 246636 247424    256   16    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata  15464  15464    120
2021年 09月 15日 星期三 13:50:51 CST
[root@localhost log]# ifconfig eth4 up
[root@localhos log]# cat /proc/slabinfo |grep skbuff_head;date
skbuff_head_cache   3516  14528    256   16    1 : tunables  120   60    8 : slabdata    908    908    420
2021年 09月 15日 星期三 13:50:58 CST
```

Anyone who can help me to diagnose it is very appreciate.